# Why Image Asset - Launcher Icon (Adaptive and legacy), i.e. res/mipmap, will delete/overwrite the res/drawable with the same name?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-mipmap, launcher-icon

I have an app_icon.png in res/drawable and I also want to create a launcher icon which also call app_icon. Image Asset prompts me that "same name already exist".

When I finish the wizard, my app_icon.png will be deleted by the Image Asset.

Any idea why the res/mipmap need to overwrite the file in res/drawable?

[image]

[image]